# Dash dcc Input, disabled attribute is doing the opposite of what i want it too

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

```
    layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Registration"),
    html.H4("Username: "),
    dcc.Input(id="username"),
    
    html.Div([
        html.H3(option[0]),
        html.Button("Yes", id="stock_y", n_clicks=0),
        html.Button("No", id="stock_n", n_clicks=0),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Input(id="stock", placeholder="Please enter stock here", disabled="True")
]),

    ])

@callback(
    Output("stock", component_property="disabled"),
    Input("stock_y", "n_clicks")
)
def enable(clicks):
    if clicks > 0:
        return "False"
```

I want the text box to be initially disabled and if user clicks the yes button than this will enable the text box. However when i open the page the text box is enabled and when i click the yes button it disables the text box. Why is this and how do i fix it?

example: [https://imgur.com/a/BqLFNID](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

tried changing false and true statements and was expecting the box to be initially disabled and become enabled after clicking yes by swapping the disabled attribute from "True" to "False"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values need to be booleans, not strings. So you should have:

```py
dcc.Input(id="stock", placeholder="Please enter stock here", disabled=True)
```

And in the callback:

```py
def enable(clicks):
    if clicks > 0:
        return False
    return True  # good to set a default, otherwise it will be set to None
```